# Issue with AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application Not Refreshing News Articles on Scraping from News Website

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have developed a Python application that scrapes news articles from the News website and then generates summaries using the OpenAI API. When running the application locally, everything works as expected, and I can retrieve up-to-date news articles and summaries. However, after deploying the application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk in the Mumbai region (ap-south-1), it seems to encounter an issue with refreshing the news content.

The problem is that the application is consistently fetching older news articles, failing to capture the latest ones from the News website. I have confirmed that the Elastic Beanstalk instance's time-zone is correctly set to Indian Standard Time (IST), so the time zone should not be causing the issue.

I appreciate any insights or troubleshooting tips that can help me identify the root cause and fix this problem to ensure my application fetches and summarizes the latest news articles from the News website as expected.

Timestamp Checking:
I examined the timestamp handling in my Python application to ensure it is correctly capturing and using the current time when making requests to the News website. This step was to verify if any time discrepancies were affecting the scraping process.